# Prove that if $p\in{\mathbb{R}},\;\;p>1$ then $(1+x)^p > 1+x^p$ with $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove that if $p\in{\mathbb{R}},\;\;p>1$,  then $(1+x)^p > 1+x^p$ with $x>0$.

I have got it using derivatives but I am looking for a smarter proof.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your proof using derivatives? It is hard to know what you mean by "smarter" without seeing it

Comment: I mean that I looking for a prove without using derivatives.

Comment: See the proof using geometric series for the generalized form of [Bernulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we can take $0<x\leq1$. Then
$$
(1+x)^p\geq1+px\geq1+px^p>1+x^p ,
$$
where we used a [generalized Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) in the first step, 
the simple comparison $x^p\leq x$ in the second step, 
and $p>1$ in the last step.

**Update:** The linked Wiki page does not seem to have an explicit proof of the generalized Bernoulli inequality for real $p>1$, so let me include a proof here that uses properties of logarithm. We have
$$
\frac1p\log(1+x)
=\frac{p-1}p\log1+\frac1p\log(1+x)
\leq\log\big(\frac{p-1}p+\frac{1+x}p\big)
=\log\big(1+\frac{x}p\big) ,
$$
where we have used the concavity of log in the second step. Now the monotonicity of log gives
$$
(1+x)^{\frac1p}\leq1+\frac{x}p ,
$$
and the substitution $y=\frac{x}p$ finishes the job.

**General comment:** Since this question involves real exponent $p$, and $x^p$ can be defined only for rational $p$ by using a finite process, the proof must involve an infinite process in some way. Thus I would argue that in this situation, using a derivative is not more "shameful" than any other proof. In the particular proof above, the infinite process is hidden under the generalized Bernoulli inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use *Bernoulli's inequality*:

- If $0<x\le1$, then $\;(1+x)^p>1+px >1+(x^{p-1})\,x$ since $p>1\ge x^{p-1}$.
- If $x>1$, set $\;x=\smash{\dfrac1u}$ ($0<u<1$). It amounts to checking $\;(1+u)^{p}>1+u^p$, which is the previous case.

Comment: That only works for integer $p$, while the OP says that $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oops! I missed that detail!

Comment: upvoted to balance the existing downvote